# PHP MySQL Pivot Table Issue

Tags: php, mysql, pivot-table

Hello everyone i want to create a timesheet aplication in php and
I have the following table structure

noi15 table

```
id (Primary)    int(11) No           
cod     text    No           
nume    text    No           
intrare     text    No            
totalsectie     text    No
```

which is like this

- id cod name      intrare     totalsectie
- 1  ABC John Doe  11/12/2015   8
- 2 ABC John Doe 11/13/2015     9
- 3 AED Andrew Peters 11/12/2015  8
- 4 AED Andrew Peters 11/13/2015  8

And the Persons Table

```
id (Primary)    int(11) No           
cod     varchar(255)    No           
name    varchar(200)    No           
sectie  varchar(80) No           
marca   varchar(6)  No           
masina
```

I have tryed something like this

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'ifnull(SUM(case when intrare = ''',
      intrare,
      ''' then totalsectie end),'''') AS ',
      intrare
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  noi15;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT noi15.id, noi15.cod, noi15.intrare, persoane.name, persoane.masina, noi15.iesire, noi15.total, noi15.totalsectie, noi15.schimb, persoane.sectie, 
    persoane.marca , noi15.reale ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM `persoane`  LEFT JOIN noi15 ON persoane.name=noi15.name AND
                   GROUP BY name');
```

But it shows me an empty query.

Thank you in advance!

PS I'm an SO novice.

Comment: Show us sample input and output values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem it was an database issue.